# Java SQLite Delete

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to delete an entry from a SQLite database with java, the code I'm using is this:

```
      public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:students.db");
      c.setAutoCommit(false);

      stmt = c.createStatement();
      String sql = "DELETE FROM Grade12 WHERE Name = james";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      c.commit();
      stmt.close();
      c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

But I keep getting the error   `java.sql.SQLException: no such column: james`

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: where name = 'james'

Comment: You might want to try your SQL statement in your database first. Some databases also help you creating those queries. Then you use the statement which worked, and you are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`String sql = "DELETE FROM Grade12 WHERE Name = 'james'"`

instead of

`String sql = "DELETE FROM Grade12 WHERE Name = james"`

Comment: @theThird Please try your query on database first to make sure that the query you are using is right. Sometime it's gets frustrating for no reason. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try with qoutes:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM Grade12 WHERE Name = 'james'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Please enclose james in quotes and try it out.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM Grade12 WHERE Name = 'james'";
```